# DB2 zOS increasing DSSIZE vs adding partition?

Tags: db2, db2-zos

I'm trying to load data into a DB2 table. The tablespace has 3 partitions with about 60M,60M,70M rows. The 3rd partition is failing to load. It gives me a warning that loading this partition's dataset will exceed the maximum size of # pages.

The DSSIZE is currently set to 4G for this table space. To increase to 8G, I would need to change the storage groups to SMS.

The data is currently partitioned by a numeric range.

- P1 00-33
- P2 33-66
- P3 66-100

Would adding another partition and reorginize the data be a better solution?

- P1 00-25
- P2 25-50
- P3 50-75
- P4 75-100

Are there any other suggestions that would help load this data?

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no application code that uses the partitioning scheme in their logic, adding a partition is a solution to your space issue.

I would suggest that you use 5 partitions instead of 4. Your data should then spread out more evenly.

```
P1 00-20                                                                    
P2 21-40                                                                    
P3 41-60                                                                    
P4 61-80                                                                    
P5 81-100
```